# Passing lists from WCF to WCF in VB

Tags: vb.net, wcf, list, for-loop, each

I'm trying to populate one list from another. I would think this code should work, but at the end of the day I get a list of identical items.

```
Public Sub WriteDatFile(ByRef lstReasons As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of LetterReason))
    Dim tmplstReason As New TCPService.LetterReason
    Dim tmplstReasons As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TCPService.LetterReason)


    'Load the letter reasons
    For Each LetterReason In lstReasons
        tmplstReason._reason = LetterReason.Reason
        tmplstReasons.Add(tmplstReason)
    Next

    RetVal = .......

End Sub
```

Now, when I set a breakpoint and check from the calling WCF I get this:

lstReason(0).Reason = One

lstReason(1).Reason = Two

lstReason(2).Reason = Three

But, when I set a breakpoint (after the load) in this subroutine I get the following output:

tmplstReason(0)._reason = Three

tmplstReason(0)._reason = Three

tmplstReason(0)._reason = Three

What's going on??? Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `LetterReason` inside the loop and add the new instance to the list. Try this

```
 For Each LetterReason In lstReasons
        Dim tmplstReason As New TCPService.LetterReason
        tmplstReason._reason = LetterReason.Reason
        tmplstReasons.Add(tmplstReason)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmplstReason._reason = LetterReason.Reason
tmplstReasons.Add(tmplstReason)
```

Look carefully. You're not actually changing tmplstReason, you're changing the ._reason property of it. You then add tmplstReason to the list 3 times.

The result is that you actually add the same thing to the list each time, and change that one object's ._reason variable each time. Since they're all the same, they all have the same value. :)